# Form / Block / Template

Tags: theming, forms, 8, blocks

I try to theme a custom form in my block.

Here my code :

> boutique.module

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function boutique_theme() {

  return array(    
        'ajout_panier_form'=> array(
            'render element' => 'form',
            'variables'=> array(
                'form'=> NULL,
            )
  )
  );
}
```

> AjoutPanierForm.php

```
/**
 * Class AjoutBlockForm.
 *
 * @package Drupal\boutique\Form
 */
class AjoutPanierForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'ajout_panier_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

        $form['#attributes']['oninput']='showPoids.value = poids.value';

        $form['poids'] = array(
            '#type' => 'range',
            '#title' => $this->t('Poids en gramme'),
            '#min' => 500,
            '#max' => 20000,
            '#default_value' => 500,
            '#step' => 100,
            '#attributes'=>array('id'=>array('poids')),
            '#description' => $this->t(""),
            '#required' => TRUE,
        );

        $form['showPoids']=array(
            '#type'=>'markup',
            '#markup'=>'<output id="showPoids" for="poids">500</output>'

        );

      $form['ajouter'] = array(
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#value' => $this->t('Ajouter'),

      );


    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
drupal_set_message('ok');

  }
```

> AjoutPanierBlock.php

```
/**
 * Provides a 'AjoutPanierBlock' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *  id = "ajout_panier_block",
 *  admin_label = @Translation("Block Ajout panier"),
 * )
 */
class AjoutPanierBlock extends BlockBase {


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {

    $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\boutique\Form\AjoutPanierForm');

    $build = [
        '#theme' => 'ajout_panier_form',
        '#form' => $form,
  ];
    return $build;

  }

}
```

And my template :

> ajout-panier-form.html.twig

```
<form{{ attributes }}>  
    {{ form.poids }} {{ form.showPoids }}
    {{ form.form_build_id }} {# required #}
    {{ form.form_id }} {# required #}
    {{ form.ajouter }}
    {{ children }}
</form>
```

My block call my template and my form is display.
But my submit doesn't call my method in my form controller where i put a

```
drupal_set_message('ok');
```

How add the actions form into template ? 
i have put `{{ children }}` but he doesn't work like the balise `{{ form }}` alone.

Comment: As I recall, rendering a form in a template file always causes the submission handler not to be called.

Comment: so we cannot do that ? i was looking for a way for themer to theme my custom form without alter the form in a preprocess function.

Comment: For what I recall, you cannot do it. There must be some questions about rendering a form in a Drupal 7 template file. What I said is what I remember  the answers said, but don't rely too much on my memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to theme a form, better override the `form.html.twig` template, because you don't know what happens in the background of this template and you don't want to do this all from scratch in your own template.

So put the complete form in the block:

```
public function build() {
  return \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\boutique\Form\AjoutPanierForm');
}
```

And copy the `form.html.twig` in your template and change it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be overriding form.html.twig, as the form template behaves differently from other templates. Take note that form.html.twig does not print the form element - leave that to Drupal so that the right actions and attributes are set.